# Datagridview is not displaying anything no column header nor data

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have seen many question and applied their results but nothing happens I still do not see any column header/data in the gridview.

The code is simple, I do get data in Dataset and I see it in debug and I simply assign to datagridview using

```
datagridviewjobs.Datasource=tempJobsDataset;
```

But nothing happens it stays empty!

Comment: are you missing datagridviewjobs.databind(); after setting DataSource and make sure AutoGenerateColumns is set to true.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can set the Datasouce directly to a dataset, try to set it to the data table you are interested in, ie tempJobsDataset.Tables["MyTable"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the Datasource of a grid to a whole DataSet, a DataSet could have dozens of tables associated with it, so it will not know which table to bind to.  Try this instead

```
datagridviewjobs.Datasource=tempJobsDataset.Tables("MyTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fill it after asigning you have to accept the changes on the table in order to get the gridview to update...

here is a complete initialisation whith a wrapping class.

```
    private void init(DataGridView datagridview, IHave_A_DataTable x)
    {
        datagridview.DataSource = x.GetDataTable();

        datagridview.Columns[datagridview.ColumnCount - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        datagridview.CurrentCell = datagridview[0, datagridview.RowCount - 1];

        x.Changed += new EventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            IHave_A_DataTable sender = o as IHave_A_DataTable;
            sender.GetDataTable().AcceptChanges();
        });
    }
```

In addition a dataset stores more than onwe table but the gridview can only accept a data table.